# Finding maxium factorial n what intiger allows! C++

Tags: c++

Sorry for bad English.
So my problem is that i need to find all possible factorials starting from 1. 
I need it to stop when Int have maximum memory used and print out maximum factorial value. My code is pretty simple, but i do not know how to get to stop loop when it reach maximum of Intiger values.

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include<climits>//
 #include <cmath>
 using namespace std;

 int main() {

int k,n=0;
unsigned  int factorial = 1;
unsigned  int factorial2=1;
unsigned  uval=INT_MAX;

cout << "Ievadi koeficentu k: ";
cin >> k;
for(int i = 1; i<=k; ++i) {
    factorial *= i;
}
cout << "Ievadita koeficenta " << k << " faktorials " << " = " <<factorial;

cout << "\nVisi iespejamie faktoriali no 1 - n: ";
for(int s = 1; s<=uval; ++s) {

    factorial2 *= s;
   if( s < uval / factorial2 ){
      cout  <<" \nkoeficenta " << s << " faktorials ir ==> " <<factorial2;
   }
}




return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the loop is going to calculate factorial to all UINT_MAX values, and most of the output will be 0 becouse memory is overloaded. 
But it should stop before it goes bigger that UINT_MAX memory! 
 Hope you all understand my problem and will help me with this.

Comment: Simple cheat: use a larger type for the calculation, but still compare against `UINT_MAX`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a 32-bit signed integer, 12! is the largest possible.

You can check this by doing

```
if (INT_MAX / fact_so_far < n)
{
   std::cout << "Max factorial " << n-1 << std::endl;
}
```

[This code STOPS when it reaches the "unable to calculate", because `INT_MAX / fact_so_far` will not multiply without overflow].

```
if (INT_MAX / fact_so_far >= n)
{
    fact_so_far *= n;
}
else
{
    std::cout << n << " is too large to calculate factorial" << std::endl;
}
```

would be the other way to do this. [Obviously with suitable loop to increment `n`]

Not that `MAX_UINT` is the max value for `unsigned int`, not for `int` [it's typically half that].

Edit to explain the logic:

The logic here is that if we divide `INT_MAX` with what our current factorial value is, it should produce a value larger than `n` [the current multiplier for the next factorial].

As a simple step through example, we pick a MAX_INT of 127:

Initial state:

```
factorial = 1, n = 1;
```

Steps:

```
n = 2, MAX_INT / factorial = 127 -> factorial *= n => 2
n = 3, MAX_INT / factorial = 63 -> factorial *= n => 6
n = 4, MAX_INT / factorial = 21 -> factorial *= n => 24
n = 5, MAX_INT / factorial = 5 -> factorial *= n = 120
n = 6, MAX_INT / factorial = 1 -> FAIL - will overflow.
```

Comment: If i understand correct, than in your if statement fact_so_far is s in my code but what is n ?

Comment: No, `fact_so_far` is `factorial1` or `factorial2`. `n` is `s` in your code.

Comment: Now it gives me only factorials what is bigger that 12!

Comment: Yes, my bad - got the `<` and `>` mixed up in my thinking. The correct will be `INT_MAX / fact_so_far > n` - will edit the answer.

Comment: @Maaverick: Crashes? Or exits?

Comment: It work now but programm is crasing and max factorial what i get is 11! And when i change > to this >= it gives me after fact 11! fact 19!

Comment: Actually, it was correct - the code was meant to STOP at `n` that is greater than the correct one. If you are using it the other way around, you need `>= n`

Comment: So is there a way to get factorial 12! ? >= And i dont know why after putting this it prints out after fact 11! fact 19! ?

Comment: Since I don't know what your code looks like, I'm not sure what you're doing and why it's not working... You probably should stop looping once you reach the maximum number...

Comment: I update the code, now you can see what i have add and did in it.

Answer (score 2):

If `factorial2 > UINT_MAX / (s+1)`, the next factorial can't be calculated.

By the way, you should use `unsigned int` for `factorial2`

Answer (score 2):

Before calculating the next factorial in the list, see if the previous one is greater than `UINT_MAX / i`. If it is, you know that the next multiplication will go out of bounds.

Comment: I am real newbie on all this, so can you tell me how excatly do it ?

Comment: @Maaverick I think you will learn more if you figure it out on your own. But I will give you a hint, the `for` statement is much more flexible than the way it is typically used.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the signed int with an unsigned one i.e. you are doing i < UINT_MAX (This is the maximum value of unsigned int) which is wrong and will result in overflow and wrong condition check.

Comment: But still `i` will always be smaller than `INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 0):

so i finaly did this with my code. Now it works but its not realy good. Maybe someone someday will need something like this as a start for his own max factorial programm. First program will ask you to insert a random number and then it calculate its factorial (only in max int borders). Then it prints out all possible int factorials. Its show only 11! as max but the max is 12! I add factorial 12! manualy, becouse the if statment cannot print out excatly the number 12 as max it prints one before. And in the end the programm shows you what is maxium possible factorial for intiger.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<climits>//
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int k, max,s;
unsigned  int factorial = 1;
unsigned  int factorial2 = 1;
unsigned  uval=INT_MAX;

cout << "Ievadi koeficentu k: ";
cin >> k;
for(int i = 1; i<=k; ++i) {
    factorial *= i;
}
cout << "Ievadita koeficenta " << k << " faktorials " << " = " <<factorial;

cout << "\nVisi iespejamie faktoriali no 1 - n: ";
for( s = 1; s<=uval; ++s) {

    factorial2 *= s;
    max=factorial2;

if( s <= uval / factorial2 ){
cout  <<" \nkoeficenta " << s << " faktorials ir ==> " <<factorial2;

}
else {
        break;
}
    }
cout  <<" \nkoeficenta " << s << " faktorials ir ==> " <<factorial2;
cout  <<" \nMaksimalais faktorials ir skaitla " << s << " faktorials ==> " <<max;



return 0;
}
```

This is what the programm looks like!

[image: Programm]
![Programm][1]